# Making TitledBorder Invisible?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent, titled-border

So I have the following JComponent that I would like to make invisible in certain conditions:

```
private final JComponent createStop()
{
    JPanel          jp;
    GridPlacement   gp;

    jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setOpaque( false );
    jp.setBorder( buildBorder(Res.getIntl(RES+"$Border.Stop")) ); // -----> Here's the problem

    gp = new GridPlacement( jp, INS_SMALL );
    gp.add( stopNo, 0,0,false,"N","NW",1,1 );
    gp.add( stopYes, 1,0,false,"N","NW",1,1 );
    gp.add( stopTimeout, 2,0,false,"N","NW",1,1 );
    gp.add( stopKill, 3,0,false,"N","NW",1,1 );
    //gp.add( new FillArea(0,0), 3,2,true,"H","C",1,1 );
    gp.add( new FillArea(0,0), 100,100,true,"B","C",1,1 );

    return jp;
}
```

I'm able to make everything invisible except for the titledBorder which doesn't go away for some reason when I do:

```
    createStop().setVisible(false);
```

Even when I try to forcibly set it to null, it still remains visible:

```
        createStop().setBorder(null);
```

Same thing when I try to do this:

```
createStop().setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

Here's how the border is created:

```
protected Border buildBorder( String s )
{
    return BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( BORDER_TITLE, s, TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, FONT_TITLE );
}
```

Is there any way I can make it invisible just like the rest of the elements of the createStop() method?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in case somebody else runs into the same problem, here's what I did to solve it:

I took the variable `jp` out of the `createStop()` method and made it a global variable.

Then, depending on the condition, I called revalidate() on the JPanel just after setting its visibility to true or false:

```
if (Condition){
    jp.setVisible(false);
    jp.revalidate();
} else {
    jp.setVisible(true);
    jp.revalidate();
}
```